# Bootstrap 3 change fluidness on certain screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, fluid

I am trying to achieve a very simple concept, but couldn't find an easy way to do it (without having to override Bootstrap's default CSS).
I am using SASS, I use the [bootstrap-sass repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/) .
My goal is to make the page "fluid" when it's on md size or below, but not "fluid" when it's bigger. Is there a simple way of doing this with bootstrap SASS, or do I have to manipulate the CSS directly?
Thanks!

Comment: You are just going to convert the idea of CSS code into SASS. Isn't it?

Comment: use a `.container` it wraps your content in a fixed width on md and lg, and adapts in xs and sm.

Comment: Look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/nagyadam2092/pen/meGwVv
If you shrink the window, it will not widen to the whole width, but have a little gap on the sides instead, and that's what I don't want: I want to be full width on sizes md, sm and xs.

Comment: You placed the background color on the H1 and not the container in your Codepen, it's not the same thing.

Comment: That's true, but I want h1 (and navbar as well) to stretch to full width on screen sizes md, sm, and xs.